# Subtracting Months/Years

Tags: python

I'm trying to subtract dates, both in the format of Month, Year. I wasn't sure if I should use datetime? I was reading over the docs and wasn't sure what would be the best way to calculate something like subtracting January 2005 from July 2008.

Comment: ...what the hell would that be? 3 years 6 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the length of time between two points, subtracting [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects is definitely the approach to take.

```
import datetime

then = datetime.datetime(year=2015, month=1, day=1)
now = datetime.datetime.now()

difference = now - then
```

This generates a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)  object

```
type(difference)  # <class 'datetime.timedelta'>

difference.days  # 351
difference.seconds  # 40732 seconds + 351 days
difference.total_seconds()  # 30367132.648078 seconds total
```

Comment: How would you programatically break up Decmeber 2008 into datetime format?

Comment: @MorganAllen well `datetime.datetime(year=2015, month=1, day=1)` Is January 1st, 2015, so what's December 1st, 2008? :P

Comment: I'm just not sure on how to write the code to get December 2015 into datetime(year=2015, month 12, day=1)

Comment: @MorganAllen with your keyboard....? Maybe I don't understand.... Do you have the *string* `"December 2015"` and you're trying to turn that into `datetime.datetime(year=2015, month=12, day=1)`? Sounds like a different (but poor quality) question. Look up string splitting, convert the number to an `int` and do a dictionary lookup on `"December"` to see which month number it is.

Comment: Ok, yes that's what I was asking :-) thank you. I didn't know if Python had an easy way of doing that, or I had to do the conversion myself.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to use `datetime.datetime` objects. Subtracting `datetime.datetime` objects generates a `datetime.timedelta` object, as exemplified below

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> someday = datetime(2005, 1, 1)
>>> someotherday = datetime(2008, 7, 1)
>>> diff = someotherday - someday
>>> print diff
1277 days, 0:00:00
```